# Search form doesn't show old values after submit laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, select, form-submit, laravel-blade

I have a search form, but it doesn't display the selected options from previously when submitted.

**Here is my form:**

```
<form role="form" class="advanced-search-form" method="post" action="{{ url('/searchresults') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Select city: </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="selectcity">
            @if (count($cities) > 0)
                @foreach ($cities as $city)
                    <option value="{{$city->id}}" @if( old('selectcity')  == $city->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{$city->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
            <button class="btn btn-light-blue-2 pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**here is my route:** `Route::post('/searchresults', 'SearchController@index');`

**The action in my controller**

```html
public function index()
{
       
    $cities = DB::table('cities')
        ->select('cities.name', 'cities.id')
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
    return view('pages.searchresults', compact('cities'));
}
```

At the moment I'm not displaying the results, I first need to fix why the form empties after submit, and does not return old values and sets selected option.

Comment: do redirect on post methods instead of return view.

Comment: First off: When working with forms and wanting to populate them you really should look into https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html. 

Secondly - is there a reason why you are not using a model for City instead of doing raw queries? 

Thirdly - to redirect back to form and keep data you can use redirect()->back()->withData() and also include ->with(compact('cities'))

Comment: [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-old) only works when you flash the old input data to your session, as documented. If you want to remember this data, you will have to flash it manually or send the selected value back to your page.

Comment: @larsemil Thanks for the tips. 2. I haven't created the model yet, my first approach was with DB queries. The thing is I don't want to redirect back but to redirect to different view

Comment: @Jerodev thank you for the advice, solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

As it's written in the documentations https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

The flash method on the Illuminate\Http\Request class will flash the current input to the session so that it is available during the user's next request to the application:

```
$request->flash();
```

You should use a redirect like that

```
return redirect('yourTarget')->withInput();
```